# how to use php $_POST[something] not user ' after [?

Tags: php, post

my code

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST)) {
        echo $_POST['username'];
    }
?>
```

but i want use $_POST[username] not use string ' .How to can i do it?

Comment: You can't do that that is called syntax

Comment: Correct Syntax is $_POST['username']

Comment: A link to read http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.donts

Comment: `const username = 'username';` -> `echo $_POST[username];`, but I'd say its a bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use without single quote in `POST`

You can declare `$postName = 'username';` and use this variable.

```
<?php
$postName = 'username';

if (isset($_POST)) {
    echo $_POST[$postName];
}
?>
```

Comment: Accept If the answer is useful.